# set::set from variadic template arguments

Tags: c++, c++20

How do I create a set from arguments of variadic templated function?

```
template<class T>
concept Int = std::same_as<T, int>;

template<Int... Ints>
std::set<int> fun (Ints... ints)
{
    // create and return a set containing arguments to this function
}
```

Comment: `return {ints...};` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand the pack using [pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) as shown below:

```
template<Int... Ints>
std::set<int> fun (Ints... ints)
{
    return {ints...};  //use unary right fold 
}
int main()
{
    std::set<int> myset = fun(1,2,3);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/19KG97jvx)

Comment: Except that this is not a unary right fold, but a [brace-enclosed initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Comment: @j6t Right, it's a pack expansion. Updated to use the correct term.